# How to get Mailbox list in batches of 100 using -ResultSize

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I have to fetch Exchange Mailboxes in batches of 100 (there are total 1m+ mailboxes in organization).
I am using the following powershell command:
`Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited`
This gives me all the mailboxes which is taking long time. I can process the result in batches of 100 so I hit this command: `Get-Mailbox -ResultSize 100`.
Seems to work fine but I'm stuck on how to bring the next 100 mailboxes.

PS: You can assume that the mailboxes are static and no changes will be made on them for indefinite time...

Answer (score 0):

You could get all the users you have, so you can have a specific number by using the count.

```
$Users = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited | select Name | Export-Csv C:\Setup\Users.csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "|" -Encoding UTF8
($users).Count
```

You will have a number as an output:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> ($users).Count
421
```

Now that you know the exact number you can export your users to a csv and split the csv to multiple csv files and then import them in a loop to get what you want.

e.g.

```
$s=0
$i=100
While ($i -le $number) {
$Users = (Get-Content C:\Setup\Users.csv)[$s .. $i]>c:\setup\Users_$i.csv
$s=$i++
$i=$i+100
}
```

after that you can import your users, from the csv and run what you want to do with them.

Hope that helps.

Edit as you don't want the thing with output into csv files.

```
$Users = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited | Select Name
$Users | Select-Object -First 100 -skip 0
```

This will give you the first 100 records then add on the `-Skip 100` to get the next 100 records by skipping the 100 records.

Comment: I don't want to dump entire result into csv file. I want to mention the page number and size in the query parameter itself.

Comment: Do you want something like: 
`$Users = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited | select Name
$Users | Select-Object -First 100 -Skip 0
$Users | Select-Object -First 100 -Skip 100
$Users | Select-Object -First 100 -Skip 200`

I Hope the select command can help you with your output.

Answer (score 0):

As StefTheo reply, you could use “skip” parameter to get the next 100 mailboxes.

```
Get-Mailbox | Select-Object -Skip 100 -First 100
```

`Skip 100` is means of start from 100th One, you can get third 100 mailboxes to use `Skip 200`

For more information, Please refer to this link:

[PowerShell - Get-Mailbox ResultSize](https://www.morgantechspace.com/2015/06/powershell-get-mailbox-resultsize.html)